# How come I get compile time error when use Collections.sort() but not with TreeSet.add(new Object())

Tags: java

How come I'm allowed to do this:

```
TreeSet<Object> treeSet = new TreeSet<Object>();
treeSet.add(new Object());
```

But not this:

```
final List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
Collections.sort(objects);
```

The first one gives me an ClassCastException but the second one gives me a compile error. As I understand it the actual problem is the same in both cases: `java.lang.Object` does not implement the **Comparable** interface.

UPDATE:
Hmm for some reason this only applies for Java 7 and not 6. 
Am I being stupid or tired? Could someone please shed some light on this?

UPDATE #2:
I do get different results depending on java versions. Please see picture:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is only hapenning at JDK7? This is happening to me and I have jdk1.6u24

Comment: I can run this with jdk1.6.0_38. I get the runtimeerror with jdk1.7.0_10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Collections.sort` requires a list of `Comparable`'s.  `TreeSet` doesn't have that restriction in the typing.  With the default constructor, the docs say it sorts by " natural ordering of its elements".  What isn't clear is how it would sort `Object`, but your problem deals with the typing.

Update: 
I missed the last part of the question.  Without looking at the stacktrace, I would guess that since the default constructor for `TreeSet` tries to sort by "natural order", internally, it is doing a cast to `Comparable`, which would cause a `ClassCastException`.

Update:
I looked closer at the javadocs for `TreeSet` ([JDK 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28%29), [JDK 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28%29)) and it says

> Constructs a new, empty tree set, sorted according to the natural
>   ordering of its elements. All elements inserted into the set must
>   implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all such elements
>   must be mutually comparable: e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a
>   ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the set. If the user
>   attempts to add an element to the set that violates this constraint
>   (for example, the user attempts to add a string element to a set whose
>   elements are integers), the add call will throw a ClassCastException.

for both.  So, if no ClassCastException happens with JDK6, perhaps it is a bug.

Comment: But how come I only get the ClassCastException when running with jdk7 and not jdk6?

Comment: When I looked closer, the javadoc states that the `TreeSet` should throw an ClassCastException when using the default constructor and adding non-`Comparable` objects.

Comment: If you add a couple items, how are things being sorted in `TreeSet` in JDK 6?

Answer (score 5):

Initially I frowned here, but you're right.

The `SortedSet` interface does not force you to specify its generic type as being `Comparable` as `TreeSet` also allows you to specify a `Comparator` for types that are not `Comparable`. The compiler can't distinguish between the two options.

Comment: But how come I only get the ClassCastException when running with jdk7 and not jdk6?

Answer (score 4):

Because `TreeSet<E>` is not restricted to objects that implements `Comparable` because you can construct it passing a `Comparator<E>`.

`Collections.sort(T)` needs that `T` implements `Comparable`. There's another method in `Collections` that accepts any object, but you need to give a `Comparator`.

In the end, it all depends if your object have a natural ordering because they implement `Comparable` or you give the objects the necessary `Comparator` to do the work.

Answer (score 2):

See the signature of sort function from Collection:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

It is expecting object implementing Comparable interface.That is why, your code showing compile time error.

But in the case of Treeset,there is no restriction that the element added should implement Comparable.It is needed only for proper working.